# Jquery adding network file path in link is also adding domain name

Tags: c#, jquery, handlebars.js

Trying to do the following

```
    "{{#each item}}",
    "<li>",
    "   <strong><a class='tp-backlog-desc-group' href={{FilePath}}>{{Name}}</a></strong>",
    "</li>",
    "{{/each}}"
```

And in file Path I am passing a network path i.e.

\storage\summary\summaryfile2.txt

but then when I click on the link when rendered it turns into

http://localhost/\storage\summary\summaryfile2.txt

Anyway I can not add the domain name so my link works and just goes to the network path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string `\storage\summary\summaryfile2.txt` is a path but `href` needs an URL and they're not same thing. Because you didn't specify any protocol (`http` or `ftp`, for example) browser will default to `http` and it'll resolve it to `localhost`. Just add right protocol (of course client must be on the same domain to access a network path from a link):

```
"   <strong><a class='tp-backlog-desc-group' href=file://{{FilePath}}>{{Name}}</a></strong>",
```

If you're not working with a physical path but it's relative to web server root then you have to resolve it server side, just change your file path like this (server side, of course):

```
path = Server.MapPath("~" + path);
```

This way your URL will be `http://yoursite/storage/summary/summaryfile2.txt`. Of course it must be available to clients and path must be a child of site virtual directory (usually paths above site root aren't accessible because of security reasons).